# Compiler errors on a play 2.3 /reactivemongo application

Tags: scala, playframework, compiler-errors, runtime-error, reactivemongo

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala using reactivemongo driver.
I've a main application that used an other module.
Friday my application compiled and executed correctly.
Now i'm getting some problem, but i didn't change any code.

This is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "recommendation-system"

version := "1.2-BETA"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.0-SNAPSHOT"
)     

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Here my compiler errors:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference to reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers encountered in class file 'JSONGenericHandlers.class'.
[error] Cannot access type GenericHandlers in package reactivemongo.api.collections. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers, or JSONGenericHandlers.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:25: type arguments [play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection] do not conform to method collection's type parameter bounds [C <: reactivemongo.api.Collection]
[error]   def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:29: wrong number of type arguments for reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder, should be 1
[error]   case class MyQueryBuilder(gqb: GenericQueryBuilder[JsObject, Reads, Writes]) {
[error]                                  ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:94: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     if (upsert) collection.update(e, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                                     ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:95: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[T]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     else collection.insert(e)
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:103: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, Json.obj("$set" -> e), GetLastError())
[error]                                                                 ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:111: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:119: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:127: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[T]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.remove(e)
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:135: could not find implicit value for parameter swriter: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]
[error]     MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(Json.obj()))
[error]                                   ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:142: could not find implicit value for parameter swriter: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]     MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(selector))
[error]                                   ^
[error] 11 errors found
[error] bad symbolic reference to reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers encountered in class file 'JSONGenericHandlers.class'.
[error] Cannot access type GenericHandlers in package reactivemongo.api.collections. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers, or JSONGenericHandlers.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:25: type arguments [play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection] do not conform to method collection's type parameter bounds [C <: reactivemongo.api.Collection]
[error]   def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:29: wrong number of type arguments for reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder, should be 1
[error]   case class MyQueryBuilder(gqb: GenericQueryBuilder[JsObject, Reads, Writes]) {
[error]                                  ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:94: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     if (upsert) collection.update(e, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                                     ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:95: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[T]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     else collection.insert(e)
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:103: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, Json.obj("$set" -> e), GetLastError())
[error]                                                                 ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:111: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:119: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : reactivemongo.core.commands.GetLastError
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern
[error]     (which expands to)  reactivemongo.api.commands.GetLastError
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:127: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[T]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     collection.remove(e)
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:135: could not find implicit value for parameter swriter: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]
[error]     MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(Json.obj()))
[error]                                   ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/models/storage/MongoObj.scala:142: could not find implicit value for parameter swriter: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]     MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(selector))
[error]                                   ^
[info] No documentation generated with unsuccessful compiler run
[warn] three warnings found
[error] 11 errors found
[error] (compile:doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 30 s, completed 13-ott-2014 11.44.28
make: *** [publish-all] Error 1
```

And here the file on which the compiler gives me the errors:

```
package recommendationsystem.models.storage

import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

// Reactive Mongo imports
import reactivemongo.api._
import reactivemongo.api.collections._
import reactivemongo.core.commands._

// Play Json imports
import play.modules.reactivemongo._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoPlugin
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator
import play.api.libs.json._

import play.api.Play.current

trait MongoObj[T] {
  def collectionName: String
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  /** Switch to implicit lazy val on production */
  implicit def db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
  /** Switch to implicit val on production */
  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName)
  /** storage formatter */
  implicit val storageFormat: Format[T]

  case class MyQueryBuilder(gqb: GenericQueryBuilder[JsObject, Reads, Writes]) {

    def sort(by: JsObject): MyQueryBuilder = {
      MyQueryBuilder(gqb.sort(by))
    }

    /**
     * Skip first s element
     * @param s number of element to skip
     * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
     */
    def skip(s: Int): MyQueryBuilder = {
      MyQueryBuilder(gqb.options(QueryOpts(s)))
    }

    /**
     * Take only l element
     * @param l number of element to take
     * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
     */
    def limit(l: Int): MyQueryBuilder = {
      val opt = gqb.options
      MyQueryBuilder(gqb.options(opt.batchSize(l)))
      //collection.find(Json.obj()).sort(sortBy).options(QueryOpts(skip, limit)).cursor[T].collect[List](limit)
    }

    /**
     * Return list of all result elements
     * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
     */
    def toList(implicit read: Reads[T]): Future[List[T]] = {
      if (gqb.options.batchSizeN > 0)
        gqb.cursor[T].collect[List](gqb.options.batchSizeN)
      else
        gqb.cursor[T].collect[List](100000)
    }

    /**
     * Return an enumerator of all elements
     * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
     */
    def toEnum(implicit read: Reads[T]): Enumerator[T] = {
      gqb.cursor[T].enumerate()
    }

    /**
     * skip parameter
     * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
     */
    def one(implicit read: Reads[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
      gqb.one[T]
    }

  }

  /**
   * Return number of all documents on collection
   */
  def count: Future[Int] = collection.db.command(Count(collection.name))

  /**
   * Insert an element to collection,
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def save(e: T, upsert: Boolean = false): Future[LastError] = {
    if (upsert) collection.update(e, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
    else collection.insert(e)
  }

  /**
   * Update an element to collection with parameter e, the element to update is selected by parameter query
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def update(query: JsObject, e: JsObject): Future[LastError] = {
    collection.update(query, Json.obj("$set" -> e), GetLastError())
  }

  /**
   * Update an element to collection with parameter e, the element to update is selected by parameter query
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def update(query: T, e: T, upsert: Boolean): Future[LastError] = {
    collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
  }

  /**
   * Update an element to collection with parameter e, the element to update is selected by parameter query
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def update(query: JsObject, e: T, upsert: Boolean = false): Future[LastError] = {
    collection.update(query, e, GetLastError(), upsert)
  }

  /**
   * Remove an element from collection,
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def remove(e: T): Future[LastError] = {
    collection.remove(e)
  }

  /**
   * Return all element in collection
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def all(implicit tformat: Format[T]): MyQueryBuilder =
    MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(Json.obj()))

  /**
   * Find elements in collection, sorted by sortBy parameter
   * Implicit T -> JsObject must be in scope
   */
  def find(selector: JsValue)(implicit tformat: Format[T]): MyQueryBuilder = {
    MyQueryBuilder(collection.find(selector))
  }

}
```

After that i've tried to updated my `build.sbt` file as following:

```
name := "recommendation-system"

version := "1.2-BETA"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"
)     

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Now my project compile, but i get the following runtime errors:

```
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/alberto/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/jars/slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/alberto/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/jars/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/alberto/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
[info] application - ReactiveMongoPlugin starting...
[info] application - ReactiveMongoPlugin successfully started with db 'bdrim'! Servers:
        [localhost:27017]
[info] application - Application has started
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/api/collections/GenericHandlers
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)[ERROR] [10/13/2014 11:23:57.603] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/api/collections/GenericHandlers
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.package$JSONCollectionProducer$.apply(jsoncollection.scala:31)
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.package$JSONCollectionProducer$.apply(jsoncollection.scala:30)
    at reactivemongo.api.DB$class.collection(database.scala:64)
    at reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB.collection(database.scala:163)
    at recommendationsystem.models.storage.MongoObj$class.collection(MongoObj.scala:25)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Similarity$.collection(Pearson.scala:52)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Pearson$.mapReduce(Pearson.scala:203)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Pearson$.calculate(Pearson.scala:217)
    at Settings$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply$mcV$sp(Settings.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$5.run(Scheduler.scala:79)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(Scheduler.scala:242)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(F
orkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 39 more

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.package$JSONCollectionProducer$.apply(jsoncollection.scala:31)
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.package$JSONCollectionProducer$.apply(jsoncollection.scala:30)
    at reactivemongo.api.DB$class.collection(database.scala:64)
    at reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB.collection(database.scala:163)
    at recommendationsystem.models.storage.MongoObj$class.collection(MongoObj.scala:25)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Similarity$.collection(Pearson.scala:52)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Pearson$.mapReduce(Pearson.scala:203)
    at recommendationsystem.algorithms.Pearson$.calculate(Pearson.scala:217)
    at Settings$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply$mcV$sp(Settings.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$5.run(Scheduler.scala:79)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(Scheduler.scala:242)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 39 more
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/api/collections/GenericHandlers
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
Uncaught error from thread [[ERROR] [10/13/2014 11:23:57.640] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(application)] Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:474)
    at reactivemongo.utils.LazyLogger$.apply(utils.scala:55)
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem$.<init>(actors.scala:670)
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem$.<clinit>(actors.scala)
    at reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver$$anonfun$7.apply(api.scala:511)
    at reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver$$anonfun$7.apply(api.scala:511)
    at akka.actor.TypedCreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(Props.scala:343)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:474)
    at reactivemongo.utils.LazyLogger$.apply(utils.scala:55)
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem$.<init>(actors.scala:670)
    at reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem$.<clinit>(actors.scala)
    at reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver$$anonfun$7.apply(api.scala:511)
    at reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver$$anonfun$7.apply(api.scala:511)
```

I think that reactivemongo or akka had been updated recently, without changing the version of the project.

What's wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem how the following:

- Delete all the files in the `$HOME/.ivy2/cache folder`
- Change the built.sbt as the following:

  name := "recommendation-system"

  version := "1.2-BETA"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ws,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache,
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"
  )

  javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"

  lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
- Give `activator clean` before `run`.

Comment: "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23", did the trick for me =) Thank you!

Comment: If you have a custom config file, or a sub-project SBT layout, the javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf" is the key getting it working as includes in config files seems ignored